# Where is this piece of The Witcher 3 music from?

Tags: the-witcher-3, game-music-identification

There is a [neat tune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dv6szOvyn58) on YouTube, originally uploaded in 2013, called the "Main Theme" of *The Witcher 3*. Judging from the date of upload, it might as well be fan-made, but it sounds really polished. Some people in the comments claim that this was from the first trailer, but I was not able to find any trailer containing this music.

Is this tune official? Where is it from?

Answer (score 5):

While possibly not the first trailer, this music piece definitely came from A trailer. The trailer referred to is the "Beautiful World of the Witcher" trailer:

This trailer was released in 2015, well after the release of the video you linked.

Comment: Nice find! I wonder where it originally came from, since this trailer is shorter than the first video.

Comment: @IllidanS4 Generally, music for games can be made quite a long time in advance, to the point that the game shifts tone since then and the music no longer fits the theme of the game. If you compare this song to those on the OST, it doesn't really have the same style as the other songs. While the other songs feel like a medieval version of rock/folk, this sounds more like a medieval version of classical music.

Comment: Definitely, although in this case, it is also due to the different composers (Adam Skorupa and Krzysztof Wierzynkiewicz didn't work on The Witcher 3).

Comment: @IllidanS4 They did work on Witcher 2. It's possible this was a leftover piece of music that they couldn't fit into W2 anymore.